# ImportError: No module named mock

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

So I am trying to use unittest.mock to mock some of my methods in my unit tests. I do:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
f = open("data/static/mock_ffprobe_response")
subprocess.check_output = MagicMock(return_value=f.read())
f.close()
```

But I am getting:

```
ImportError: No module named mock
```

I tried:

```
pip install mock
```

It's still not working.

Comment: this module is available in version 3.3 ,, what is your version

Comment: My version is 2.7. Is there any alternative?

Comment: According to Google this should work also on 2.7.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`unittest` is a built-in module; `mock` is an external library (pre-3.3 betas, anyway).  After installing `mock` via `pip install`, you import it not by using

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
```

but

```
from mock import MagicMock
```

Edit: `mock` has been included in the `unittest` module (since Python3.3), and can be imported by `import unittest.mock`.

Comment: On Python 3.3+ you need to do the opposite of what this answer suggests: `from unittest.mock import MagicMock`

Answer (score 24):

For Python 2.7:

Install mock:

```
pip install mock
```

Then in the test code, use this import:

```
from mock import patch, MagicMock
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to support both, Python 2 and Python 3, you can also use following:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3, 3):
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock
else:
    from mock import MagicMock
```

or, if you don't want to import `sys`

```
try:
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock
except ImportError:
    from mock import MagicMock
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're using **Python 3.3+**, change

```py
import mock
```

to

```py
from unittest import mock
```

Or you can keep all the code the same and run this shell command instead:

```bash
pip install mock
```

This command works on any Python version but changing the code is preferable because then other people running your code won't run into that import error anymore.

This error happens because [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/library/unittest.mock.html) was added in Python 3.3, and there is [a backport](https://pypi.org/project/mock/) on PyPI for older Python versions. So if your code used to be Python 2, it's probably trying to import the backport.

---

[`pyupgrade`](https://pypi.org/project/pyupgrade/) is a tool you can run on your code to rewrite those imports and remove other no-longer-useful leftovers from Python 2.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason, `import unittest.mock` did not work for me, I had to do

```
from unittest import mock
```

Answer (score 5):

I was facing issues on import when running `pytest`. It turned out to be my `pytest` was of 2.7 version of `python`, while my `virtualenv` was a 3.6 `python`. I fixed it by doing a `pip install` from my `virtualenv` and then using the `pytest` from `env/bin/pytest`.

Answer (score 3):

For your version, I would suggest go to http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/unittest/mock.py and use this source to your advantage.