# Pytest user input simulation

Tags: python-3.x, user-input, pytest

I am brand new to pytest and trying to work my way through it. 
I currently am programming a small CLI game which will require multiple user inputs in a row and I cannot figure out how I can do that. 
I read a bunch of solutions but did not manage to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
class Player:
def __init__(self):
    self.set_player_name()
    self.set_player_funds()

def set_player_name(self):
    self.name = str(input("Player, what's you name?\n"))

def set_player_funds(self):
    self.funds = int(input("How much money do you want?\n"))
```

I simply want to automate the user input for those two requests.
(ie: a test that would `input "Bob"` and `test: assert player.name=="Bob"`

Can someone help out with that? 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851323/pytest-how-to-test-a-function-with-input-call)?

Comment: I did, I couldn't figure out how it worked. But I mostly understood my program was poorly designed. I do not want to simulate a user input, I just want to select some specific inputs and test outcomes programmatically.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Quite elegant way to test inputs is to mock input text by using `monkeypatch` fixture. To handle multiple inputs can be used `lambda` statement and iterator object.

```
def test_set_player_name(monkeypatch):
    # provided inputs
    name = 'Tranberd'
    funds = 100
    
    # creating iterator object
    answers = iter([name, str(funds)])

    # using lambda statement for mocking
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda name: next(answers))

    player = Player()
    assert player.name == name
    assert player.funds == funds
```

`monkeypatch` on [docs.pytest.org](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html).
`Iterator object` on [wiki.python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator).