# How to simulate two consecutive console inputs with pytest monkeypatch

Tags: python-3.x, tdd, pytest

The module "overwrite_file" (see code example) asks for input of a new filename if the first user input is answered with "n"

In my test setup I use two consecutive monkeypatch.setattr calls to simulate the input.
The result is an endless loop if i use the order as follws:

```
monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda overwrite: "n")
monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda new_name: new_filename)
```

The second monkeypatch.setattr call is activated and 'new.pkl' is assigned to the variable overwrite.

If I change the order of the monkeypatch commands as so:

```
monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda new_name: new_filename)
monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda overwrite: "n")
```

I get an AssertionError as 'n' is assigned to the variable new_name and a file calld "n" is created.

How do I get the intended test functionality?

Interpreter: Python 3.8

```
from os.path import exists, join, dirname
import pickle
import pytest


def overwrite_file(filename):
    # loop until overwrite existing file or input of a file name which does not exist
    dump_file = False
    while not dump_file:
        if exists(filename):
            overwrite = input(f"overwrite {filename} (y/n): ")
            if overwrite in ["y", "Y"]:
                dump_file = True
            if overwrite in ["n", "N"]:
                new_name = input("new filename: ")
                filename = join(dirname(filename), new_name)
        else:
            dump_file = True

    return filename


@pytest.fixture()
def pickle_test_env(tmpdir_factory):
    a_dir = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('src_dir')
    a_file = a_dir.join('already_there.pkl')
    with open(a_file, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump({"C": 27.1, "S": -8.2, "T": 29.7}, f)
    return a_dir


def test_new_filename_if_file_exists(pickle_test_env, monkeypatch):
    """ is overwrite_file returning a valid new filename if filename exists
    and should not be overwritten? """
    filename = 'already_there.pkl'
    new_filename = 'new.pkl'
    assert exists(join(pickle_test_env, filename))
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda new_name: new_filename)
    monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda overwrite: "n")
    assert overwrite_file(join(pickle_test_env, filename)) == join(pickle_test_env, new_filename)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last monkeypatch will win out against all the others, so `input(f"overwrite {filename} (y/n): ")` is getting `"n"`, and so is `input("new filename: ")`. To provide the desired inputs in the correct order, we can monkeypatch a method that will cycle its responses

```
responses = iter(['n', new_filename])
monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda msg: next(responses))
```

Note that `responses` is an iterator object — that is, calling `next()` on it will return the next item in the list. If `input()` is called more times than there are items in the list, `StopIteration` will be raised. An optional default value may be provided, avoiding the `StopIteration` exception, and allowing `input()` to be called forever and ever:

```
next(responses, '\n')
```

There may be a cleaner way to provide stdin to `input()`, but I'm at a loss at the moment.