# Pytest asserting a function with a return value that is coming from a user input

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

**Edit**: I am flagging my own question as duplicate. My problem has a similar solution to this thread [How to test a function with input call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851323/how-to-test-a-function-with-input-call/36377194#36377194).

I have a question regarding unit tests in python.

I have implemented the following function:

```py
def prompt():
    while True:
        try:
            choice = input("What do you want to do? ")
        except EOFError:
            exit("Program Terminated.")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit("Program Terminated.")

        if choice in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '0']:
            return int(choice)
```

and to test it, I have:

```py
def test_prompt():
    assert prompt() ...
```

My question is, how do I test my `prompt()` function with `pytest`? So far, I don't have problems with my other functions since their return value does not depend on the user input.

PS: If this question is duplicated, can you pls drop the link and I'll give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: This one looks pretty similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36377194/786559 . You replace the `input()` function with another function that returns a known string (`Mark` in that example). Also see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59998012/786559) if you want to test a sequence of user inputs.

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă, okay, allow me to read it

Comment: Agreed, the `EOFError` is easily simulated if you provide an explicit file-like object as an argument. The `KeyboardInterrupt` is harder to simulate, because it's not related the file you read from, but to a signal received by your program.

Comment: Let me get back to you guys after I finish reading it. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I flagged my own question as duplicate. Thank you for helping me out