# How to answer input call from console script in pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm currently writing a module which uses `console_script` in `setup.py` to create scripts at installation time. For performing the tests I use the plugin `pytest-console-scripts` to execute those scripts. One of the functions I want to test involves a `input()` call to get an anwer from the user ('y'es or 'n'o). But I do not have any idea on how to mock this input.

A sample test using `pytest-console-scripts` looks like:

```py
import pytest

def test_my_function(script_runner):
    # first option is the console script to be run followed by arguments
    ret = script_runner.run('myscript', '--version')
    assert ret.success
```

This can be used when the console script does not involve user action. How can this be solved?

Many thanks in advance, regards, Thomas

EDIT: the provided solutions in [How to test a function with input call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851323/how-to-test-a-function-with-input-call) may solve my question only partially. My intention is to test the functionality through the console script, but not importing the module containing the function called through that script - if this is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test a function with input call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851323/how-to-test-a-function-with-input-call)

Comment: I already stumbled across that link, the solution requires the module to be installed. My intention is to test the module through the console script. However, it seems that I may have to load that function from the package and do the test that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating a lot more through Google I came across a solution, which worked perfectly for me:

```py
# pip install pytest-mock pytest-console-scripts

...

def test_user_input(script_runner, mocker):
    # optional use side_effect with any kind of value you try to give to
    # your tested function
    mocker.patch('builtins.input', return_value='<your_expected_input>')
    # use side_effect=<values> instead if you want to insert more than one value

    # Options have to be seperated
    # Example: ('my_prog', '-a', 'val_a', '-b', 'val_b')
    #      or: ('my_prog', '-a val_a -b val_b'.split(' '))
    ret = script_runner.run('my_prog')
    assert ret.success
    assert ret.stdout == <whatever>
    # or assert 'string' in ret.stdout
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect for further possibilities of how to use `side_effect`.