# How to Mock Import for Read the Docs?

Tags: python, mocking, read-the-docs

### Problem:

I have been fighting with [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.io).  An imported module interacts with I/O, so the documentation does not contain any text.  *But the build does not fail.*

### Attempted Solution:

I am trying to use `mock` or `MagicMock` in doc/conf.py but it isn't working.

### Desired Solution

Basically, I would like to `mock` the entire import.  So RTD does **not** attempt to run any of the code.  Just generate documentation from the DocStrings.

I simply want to `mock` **ALL** of the elements for a module.  The **classes**, **functions**, and **variables**.  *Anything with a DocString.*

Currently I **MUST** install the project inside a virtualenv, to satisfy the import.  I would like to avoid this, if it isn't necessary.  Right now... If I don't, again the documentation does not contain any text.  *Again, the build does not fail.*

### Details

#### example.py

```py
"""Basic DocSting Comments"""
from external.module import *

foo = module()
foo.connect()
"""
I want this to show up in RTD.
"""
```

My specific case can be found [here](http://asterisk-ivr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readthedocs.html).

#### docs/conf.py

```py
from mock import MagicMock

MOCK_MODULES = ['external.module', 'eternal.module.module', 'external.module.module.connect']
for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = MagicMock()
```

I have tried a dozen different things, with no luck.  Using `mock` and `MagicMock`, different `advanced settings` in RTD.  **All with no luck.**

### An Ugly Hack:

I did come across an ugly hack.  But it defeats the purpose of using DocStrings.  Writing the code a second time so RTD can catch the DocStings, may as well write it in a separate document.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    this = foo.connect()
    """
    This is where the real DocStrings go.
    """
else:
    this = 'this is the connect'
    """
    This is where the RTD DocStrings would go
    """
```

*I do not want to end up with twice the code, just to add some documentation.*

### MySQL Connector/Python

I would also like to use this with the MySQL Connector.  Since RTD also breaks when it encounters this package.  And I can not fix it with `requirements.txt`.

```py
import mysql.connector as db

db_connection = db.connect(**my_config)
"""
Perhaps I want to include some details here.
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution that I found on [this blog post](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-make-your-sphinx-documentation-compile-with-readthedocs-when-youre-using-numpy-and-scipy/) worked for me. I wanted to mock `open3d` and I was able to do that with:

```py
from unittest import mock

# Mock open3d because it fails to build in readthedocs
MOCK_MODULES = ["open3d"]
for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = mock.Mock()
```

Note that you need to import `mock` from `unittest` because unittest.mock is a builtin module starting with Python 3.3 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58757462/6942666)).

If you wanted to mock multiple packages, you could do something like:

```py
from unittest import mock

# Mock open3d because it fails to build in readthedocs
MOCK_MODULES = ["open3d", "numpy", "matplotlib", "matplotlib.pyplot"]
for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = mock.Mock()
```